# Need help interpreting linear/nonlinear time series

Tags: time-series, linear-model, seasonality

I have a set of data, which i am tasked to find out anything that i could from this set of one dimensional data.
Im looking at the ACF and PACF plot. Can anyhow determine if below indicates seasonality? if the data is from a linear process? or a non linear one?
what else should i look at to determine these?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

im a total newbie in time series, this set of data is the first actual data that i got to actually try and analyse. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: IMG]

[image: IMG]

[image: IMG]

I've added a few more plots. the time series plot for the whole of data isnt helpful but i think from here, i can say that there is no trend and is of constant variance?
upon zooming in, i saw patterns from t=1 to t=100 then from t=101 to t=200. then the pattern repeats all over again. I have 4000 plus of data points of unknown origin.
I was hinted that the data is of non linear nature rather than linear.. but i would have to find out more and support my claim. However, the plot for mutual information is showing that MI is not significantly different from zero hence i suspected that the data is not nonlinear.

The link below is my data set.
http://www.filetolink.com/b7e2e49597

[EDITED]
[[image: IMG]][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjTI3.png)

[image: IMG]

I've generated a few more for x[t] to x[t-10] but all are showing random clouds like the ones above with no patterns.

Comment: Whatever "below" refers to appears to be missing, but is crucial for understanding the question.

Comment: @whuber I've added the missing images. thanks for informing!

Comment: Gee they might have started you off with something simpler, where the signals are a little clearer. If we assume that the data are drawn from an ARMA model, it's hard to guess its order from this, but it's at least ARMA(1,1) and there's some indication of seasonality at lag 12, possibly an SAR component -- *is it monthly data*? I don't know of any way to reliably discern general non-linearity from an ACF/PACF pair, though some kinds might show up with particular patterns.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for helping. I was told it is highly likely to be of nonlinear, but i wasnt given much information. i tried googling but there isnt much information online with regard to nonlinearity. i could run some tests but i am not supposed to. i have to infer from all the descriptive plots!

Comment: Do you have any plots of (say) $y_t$ vs $y_{t-1}$? -- that's where I'd suggest to start looking for nonlinearity if you don't already know anything about the process (and if you do, it's probably relevant). Depending on what that looked like, I might also consider looking at $y_{t}-y_{t-1}$ or $y_{t} - y_{t-12}$ plotted against $y_{t-1}$

Comment: @Glen_b I've added them above in the post. hmm. the graphs appears random so i wasnt sure where to proceed from here... I have totally no idea about anything from the process!

Comment: The first "delay plot" (i.e. the one I asked for) *doesn't* look random to me. There's clear hints of some kind of nonlinear association there. Further, there's distinct indication of periods of short term [cycles in the time plot](http://i.imgur.com/zh9VSN1.png), suggesting that there's perhaps some almost-loops in phase space (perhaps even suggesting a chaotic system) - that would be consistent with the delay plot. I'm not saying that's what it *is* but it at least suggests those lines as a possibility. These features clearly suggest that the ACF and PACF can't give you much of the story.

Comment: You might want to consider taking your delay plot and joining the points via lines which follow a rainbow palette as time proceeds (so you can see how they progress through time)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot for your help! it is very useful. I believe it is a chaotic time series too.